# How does dbms_scheduler running every x hours/ minutes handle daylight saving time?

Tags: oracle, dst, dbms-scheduler

I have a dbms_scheduler job which has to run every 4 hours, in timezone 'Europe/Berlin'

My question is: what happens on days with a change in daylight saving time?

Let's say, last runtime was 01:00 AM. Not time either is set from 02:00AM to 03:00AM or from 03:00AM to 02:00AM.

Is the next runtime of my job after 3 hours in the first and after 5 hours in the second case or will it be just after 4 hours, regardless of the change in daylight saving time?